# RuntimeWarning from numpy after installing packages through anaconda

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I installed anaconda to do some Machine Learning work and used the navigator to setup a separate environment with ML packages.

When I try to run a simple `from sklearn import tree` in a Jupyter notebook, I get this error message:

`/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 192 from C header, got 216 from PyObject
  return f(*args, **kwds)`

Every package in that environment is updated to its latest version, including numpy 1.16.4 and sklearn 0.21.2

This is with python 3.7.4 on MacOs

Comment: Not exactly the same package, but [an issue on a different sublibrary](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/272) in `scikit-learn` suggests downgrading NumPy.  So, perhaps try `conda install numpy=1.16.1`.